# Why does bootstrap break wordpress admin?

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, plugins

Consider the following plugin code for wordpress:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: test
 * Description: This plugin is just a test for bootstrap css
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: Gavin Simpson
 * License: GPL2
*/

class testclass
{
    private static $instance;
    public static function get_instance_advert() 
    {
        if( null == self::$instance )
        {
            self::$instance = new testclass();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    private function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'inistyleheets'));
    }
    function inistyleheets()
    {
        wp_register_style( 'mybootstrap', plugins_url() . '/test/assets/bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');   
        wp_enqueue_style('mybootstrap');
    }
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'testclass', 'get_instance_advert'));
?>
```

When activating the above, the 'Screen Options' button in Wordpress Admin stops working.

The problem is 100% related to loading the Bootstrap css only, hence the example doesn't load bootstrap itself. In my production code, bootstrap works perfectly, it just breaks the 'Screen Options' button as described, just like the basic plugin code above.

I have tried all the basic themes, i.e. twentyfourteen, twentyfifteen& twentysixteen. No luck with any of them, all the same result.

Comment: inspect the console and the rendered css?

Comment: console empty. rendered css shows nothing obvious.

Comment: the only thing i can think of : If you can see the click event on the button, maybe bootstrap is covering over the button with another div it has changed the rules for.

Comment: Yeah a ton of maybes. Oh well, I have to find a solution, so will update when I have an answer. Thanks David.

Comment: Message to the future: There once was an idea for HTML to have scoped CSS files - the `scoped` attribute - but it was deprecated, but then came replacement - [`@scope` rule in CSS itself](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade-6/#scoped-styles) which is currently only supported by latest Chrome (v 118/119) (as of 2023/08) - so the future solution will be around wrapping the bootstrap compiled CSS into this :-)

Comment: with SCSS(sass) - you can achieve similar already: wrap the SCSS imports into `.editor-styles-wrapper{}`, yes, you can do `.editor-styles-wrapper{ @import "yourfile"; }`, it will be prepended before everything - mostly works as expected, except the `:root` variables - those you would have to rewrite probably manually...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long winded solution, so will not repeat it here, but the link is 
https://rushfrisby.com/using-bootstrap-in-wordpress-admin-panel. (Yes, I know posting a link is not cool, but I do not want to copy and paste someone else's solution)

The bottom line is, you need to wrap any code you might want to add Bootstrap CSS to, and the solution in the above link takes care of loading Bootstrap in a way that works very nicely.

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: Site has changes to https, and the link adds a trailing backspace, so fails. Not sure how to get around that. copy and paste https://rushfrisby.com/using-bootstrap-in-wordpress-admin-panel into the address bar and it should work.

Comment: @GavinSimpson why would you dynamically rebuild bootstrap css? Why not do this once and simply add it to the plugin folder? Also, how does this actually stop things from breaking? Wrapping bootstrap in a wrapper class doesnt prevent other plugins or wordpress core css from overwriting common selectors. For example, `.card` is used by wordpress core in forms.css and it sets max width and other attributes that are inherited. Adding a wrapper class does not fix this.

Comment: Sorry Jeremy, this was in 2016 and I could not even try to remember anything about it. I certainly do not use bootstrap anymore, nor do any of my current clients.

Comment: @GavinSimpson and what do you DO use? Anyways, the whole site seems to be taken down for public. That's why answers should contain at least the basic idea :-)

Comment: @jave, yes I agree fully about the link posting problem. Sadly at that time I did not have the time to duplicate the post, nor did I have permission to do so. Nowadays I do 100% custom themes for Woocommerce sites only, so I do not need bootstrap. The less outside code the better, as much less work to do over time.

Comment: @GavinSimpson so I assume you've created some sort of bootstrap of your own then right ? :-)

Comment: You could say that I guess, but it's more like years of coding experience and code snippets coming in handy on advanced custom sites.

Answer (score 1):

For the case of the "Screen Options" button not working ( and possibly some other cases ) you can try to use

```
.hidden[style*='display: block'] {
    display:block !important;
}
```

in some CSS loaded after bootstrap. Limited testing is showing that the button now works but the contents of the dropdown do look different due to Bootstrap styling. Because of this I've limited the enqueuing of bootstrap to only the admin screens I really need to have it on. I'm not sure it's worth it to me to try to fix the styling of that element.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue is with a classname on the controls within the Screen Options panel, wordpress `load-options css` contains an entry that targets elements with the 'hidden' class and sets '`display: none`' that makes sure those element are not displayed initially.

when you click the "Screen Options" button it triggers a javascript function that should make that panel appear because it sets a style property on those elements with 'display: block' this should override css statements.

however the bootstrap css also has a css statement that targets the classname 'hidden' but contains 'display: none !important' the '!important' causes the bootstrap css statement to keep overriding the 'display: block' that is set on the element itself. so a dirty solution would be to remove the !important part from the bootstrap css.